# Drupal 9 - Ajax callback working only once

Tags: php, ajax, forms, drupal, callback

I'm building site on Drupal 9.4 and i have some trouble with Ajax callback in my .module file in a user form alter.

The functionality is not very complicated, I display the previously uploaded images (in a multiple image fields) in a field, accompanied by a delete button.

Another field where I display the number of images that can still be uploaded.
The callback is called on each delete button to do 2 things:

1- delete the reference to the image in the photo field.

2- increase the number of images that can be uploaded by 1.

In my callback, if I just do the 1, everything works. But if I add the ajax response with the field update to increase the number, the first delete works and the field increases by 1.

But if I try to delete a second one, I get an error that says the callback could not be found.
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException: The specified #ajax callback is empty or not callable.

Here is my code:

```
function main_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id === 'user_form') {
    /** @var \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user */
    $user = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    $already_uploaded_files = getUserPictureFiles($user);
    $nbre_file = count($already_uploaded_files);
    $callback = 'remove_user_picture_callback';

    if ($nbre_file < 10) {
      $form['field_photos'] = [
        '#title' => t('Vos photos'),
        '#type' => 'dropzonejs',
        '#max_files' => (10 - $nbre_file),
        '#dropzone_description' => t('Déposez les fichiers ici pour les télécharger'),
        '#attributes' => [
          'id' => 'field-photos',
        ],
      ];
      $form['photos_left'] = [
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'p',
        '#value' => t(10 - $nbre_file . " photo(s) restante(s)"),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="field-photos-left">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
      ];
    }
    if ($nbre_file === 10) {
      $form['field_photos'] = [
        '#title' => t('Vos photos'),
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => t("Nombre maximum de photos atteint."),
      ];
    }

    if ($already_uploaded_files) {
      $form['saved_uploaded_files'] = [
        '#type' => 'value',
        '#value' => $already_uploaded_files,
        '#attributes' => ['id' => 'save-uploaded-files'],
      ];

      $form['user_pictures_container'] = [
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => [
          'class' => ['user-photos-container'],
          'id' => ['user-photos-container'],
        ],
      ];
      foreach ($already_uploaded_files as $key => $file) {
        $form['user_pictures_container']['picture_container_' . $key] = [
          '#type' => 'container',
          '#attributes' => [
            'class' => ['image-square-container'],
            'id' => ['image-square-container-' . $file->id()],
          ],
        ];
        $form['user_pictures_container']['picture_container_' . $key]['user_uploaded_picture_' . $key] = [
          '#type' => 'html_tag',
          '#tag' => 'img',
          '#attributes' => [
            'src' => $file->createFileUrl(),
          ],
        ];
        $form['user_pictures_container']['picture_container_' . $key]['remove_picture_' . $key] = [
          '#type' => 'button',
          '#name' => 'remove-button-' . $file->id(),
          '#attributes' => [
            'class' => ['user-picture-delete-icon-field'],
            'data-name' => 'remove-button-' . $file->id(),
          ],
          '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => $callback,
            'wrapper' => 'field-photos-left',
            'effect' => 'fade',
            'event' => 'click',
            'prevent' => 'submit',
            'progress' => [
              'type' => 'throbber',
              'message' => t('Suppression de la photo...'),
            ],
          ],
        ];
      }
    }
```

And the callback with functions called inside

```
function remove_user_picture_callback($form, FormStateInterface $form_state): AjaxResponse {

  // Get user Entity.
  $user = getUserEntity($form_state);
  // Get trigger fid.
  $fid = getFid($form_state);

  // Delete picture reference from user field_photos,
  deletePictureReference($user, $fid);

  return updateNbrePhotoUploaded($form, $form_state);
}



function updateNbrePhotoUploaded($form, FormStateInterface $form_state): AjaxResponse {
  $user = getUserEntity($form_state);
  $already_uploaded_files = getUserPictureFiles($user);
  $nbre_file = count($already_uploaded_files);

  $elem['photos_left'] = [
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'p',
    '#value' => t(10 - $nbre_file . " photo(s) restante(s)"),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="field-photos-left">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  ];

  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#field-photos-left', $elem));

  return $response;
}

/**
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 *
 * @return string
 */
function getFid(FormStateInterface $form_state): string {
  $element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#name'];
  return substr($element, strpos($element, '-') + 8);
}

/**
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 *
 * @return \Drupal\user\Entity\User
 */
function getUserEntity(FormStateInterface $form_state): User {
  $form_state_user = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  return User::load($form_state_user->id());
}

/**
 * @param \Drupal\user\Entity\User $user
 * @param string $fid
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException
 */
function deletePictureReference(User $user, string $fid): void {
  $field_photos = $user->get('field_photos');
  $field_photos_values = $field_photos->getValue();

  // Get the index to remove
  $index_to_remove = array_search($fid, array_column($field_photos_values, 'target_id'));
  $field_photos->removeItem($index_to_remove);

  $user->save();
}

/**
 * Return array of user picture Files entity.
 *
 * @param $user
 *
 * @return array
 */
function getUserPictureFiles($user): array {
  $user_pictures = $user->get('field_photos')->getValue();
  $files = [];

  if ($user_pictures) {
    foreach ($user_pictures as $user_picture) {
      if (array_key_exists('target_id', $user_picture)) {
        /** @var File $file */
        $file = File::load($user_picture['target_id']);
        $files[] = $file;
      }
    }
  }

  return $files;
}
```

I searched everywhere for the same error in this context but...
If someone can help !
Thanks you

Comment: Are you sure on submit that second form field exists ? I guess on form build, you don't have the second form field.

Comment: I'll investigate and come back. But what should be the good way to do the Ajax Response if it is not this ?

Comment: I finally got it to work. I exported the part of the form that was causing the problem, in a separate form, on another page, dedicated to photo management.